# HVAC furnace making weird noise

Tags: furnace

when the HVAC heat running it making this high frequency noise: https://youtube.com/shorts/HCObFKIxOJ8?feature=share

but the heat is working fine, should I call somebody to check?

Comment: Is it a brand new install?

Comment: The whole system is 20 years old, but the control board is replaced a year ago.